# Is it possible for go-xorm to detect DATETIME(3) types?

Tags: mysql, database, go

My code ultimately ends up in this section of `go-xorm`:

```
// formatTime format time as column type
func (engine *Engine) formatTime(sqlTypeName string, t time.Time) (v interface{}) {
    switch sqlTypeName {
    case core.Time:
        s := t.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05") //time.RFC3339
        v = s[11:19]
    case core.Date:
        v = t.Format("2006-01-02")
    case core.DateTime, core.TimeStamp:
        v = t.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05")
    case core.TimeStampz:
        if engine.dialect.DBType() == core.MSSQL {
            v = t.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05.9999999Z07:00")
        } else {
            v = t.Format(time.RFC3339Nano)
        }
    case core.BigInt, core.Int:
        v = t.Unix()
    default:
        v = t
    }
    return
}
```

The problem is, my actual type in the DB is `datetime(3)` -- xorm recognizes this as just `datetime` though, effectively truncating my ms precision. Is there a way around this?

This is a fundamental dependency in a project I'm working on, so not using xorm isn't an option at this time unfortunately.

Comment: See https://github.com/go-xorm/xorm/issues/1006

Comment: That's my issue that I posted to the repo 

Comment: You should format the time yourself. When exactly is it going through this code and why?